# UI Tabs reloading issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, tabs

I'm having a bit of issue with UI Jquery tabs.

On one of my pages I include UI tabs. 
Then in the footer of my website I include few links to specific tabs, so user can link to specific tabs so for instace they can go from:

www.mydomain.com
to 
www.mydomain.com/subpage/#tab-1 
or
www.mydomain.com/subpage/#tab-2

and that works fine, however when I'm at

www.mydomain.com/subpage/#tab-1

and try to switch to:

www.mydomain.com/subpage/#tab-2 
the tab is not reloading and still displaying
www.mydomain.com/subpage/#tab-1

I have tried to reload page using `onClick="window.location.reload()` but is not working however when I add `target="_blank"` to `<a>` tag it works fine. Can anyone identify an issue here and help to resolve it.

http://take1.56degrees.co.uk

Comment: your question is not clearly understood, can you please set up a jsFiddle or share your URL?

Comment: without the example markup, demo code or a crystal ball its hard to figure out the problem you are having

Comment: would also help to break up huge run on sentences in your question

Comment: @Johnx ha, crystal ball! well done, sir!

Comment: @Johnx see link below, sorry for not being clear enough
http://take1.56degrees.co.uk